# How to i can use UTF-8 in curl

Tags: curl, utf-8, webhooks

Im trying to send text from curl with my language but it not show correctly
M�y t�nh �? b?t

i tried Charset=utf-8 but it not working

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; Charset=utf-8" --data-ascii "content=Máy tính đã bật" https://discord.com/api/webhooks/abc
```

Comment: Use `--data-urlencode` instead of `--data-ascii`?